# How can I find maximum along multiple axes of a multidimensional numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array of these dimensions

`data.shape
(categories, models, types, events, days) ->  (10, 11, 50, 100, 14)`

Now, I want to find the maximum of the 14 days for all events for each of the 11 models. But I am not sure how to do it in the `numpy` way. I am not sure if this is correct.

```
modelmax = []
nmodels = 11

for modelcount in range(nmodels):
    modelmax.append(np.max(data[0][modelcount][:], axis=2))
```

As an example, for the 100 events:

```
np.max(data, axis=4)[0][0][0])

[ 3.9264417   3.3029506   3.0707457   3.6646023   1.7508441   3.1634364
  6.195052    1.5353022   1.8033538   1.4508389   1.3882699   2.0849068
  3.654939    6.6364765   3.92829     6.6467876   1.5442419   4.639682
  9.361191    5.261462    1.7438816   5.6970205   2.4356377   1.6073244
  2.6177561   6.886767    3.890399    2.8880894   1.9826577   1.0888597
  4.3763924   3.8597727   1.790302    1.0277777   6.270729    9.311213
  2.318774    2.9298437   1.139397    0.9598383   3.0489902   1.6736581
  1.3983868   2.0979824   4.169757    1.0739225   1.5311266   1.4676268
  1.726325    1.8057758   2.226462    2.6197987   4.49518     2.3042605
  5.7164993   1.182242    1.5107205   2.2920077   2.205539    1.4702082
  2.154468    2.0641963   4.9628353   1.9987459   2.1360166   1.7073958
  1.943267    7.5767093   1.3124634   2.2648168   1.1504744   3.210688
  2.6720855   2.998225    4.365262    3.5410352  10.765423    4.6292825
  3.1789696   0.92157686  1.663245    1.5835482   3.1070056   1.6918416
  8.086268    3.7994847   2.4314868   1.6471033   1.1688241   1.7820593
  3.3509188   1.3092748   3.7915008   1.018912    3.2404447   1.596657
  2.0869658   2.6753283   2.1096318   8.786542  ]
```

I have also tried

`np.max(dryflow[0][:], axis=3)`

But these multidimensional indices are leaving me confused.

Comment: And what about `categories` and `types`?

Comment: @Chiel I am trying to reduce the complexity of the problem for understanding purposes. But if I could have the daily maximums for category, model, type and event, that would be swell....I am just very confused regarding the multi-dims, and I am probably not relaying what I don't understand...

Comment: Eventually, I will take the `log` of the 14 day maximums and find the overall maximum and minimum for every type...Hope it explains a bit..

Comment: In `numpy` it is better to use `[0,0,0,0]` style of indexing rather than `[0][0][0][0]`.  Sometimes they produce the same thing, but sometimes the differences give problems.  Also with arrays `[:]` does nothing for you.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks! I didn't know there was any difference. BTW, can you expand a little bit on `[:]` doing nothing..

Comment: @maximusdooku It is unclear what you want to retain. So do you want to have for each `event` and each `model` the maximum over the days? So that you have `event*model` number of maxima?

Comment: `[0][0]...` does a separate Python indexing step for each dimension; `[0,0,..]` is one indexing step, handled directly by `numpy`.  `[:]` just means return everything in that dimension.  It is not the same as `[0,:,0...]`.

Answer (score 9):

If you want the maximum over `days` for each combination of `(category, model, type, event)`, for a resulting shape of (10, 11, 50, 100, 1):

`np.max(data, axis=4)`

If you want the maximum over `days` and  `types` for each combination of `(category, model, event)`, for a resulting shape of (10, 11, 100, 1):

`np.max(data, axis=(2,4))`